# Heroku logs say "No module named 'urlparse'" when I use import urlparse

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, flask

I'm having trouble using the following lines of code from https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-python

```
import os
import psycopg2
import urlparse

urlparse.uses_netloc.append("postgres")
url = urlparse.urlparse(os.environ["DATABASE_URL"])

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    database=url.path[1:],
    user=url.username,
    password=url.password,
    host=url.hostname,
    port=url.port
)
```

I'm using Python 3.6.2

In my Heroku logs I'm seeing:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urlparse'

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Python on AWS Lambda also brings me here!

Answer (score 19):

`urlparse` has been moved to a new module in python 3

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
```

Read more here: https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.parse.html

Comment: Thanks for the response! When I made the change you suggested  I received a different error. Now, in the Heroku logs, I'm seeing: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'uses_netloc'

Comment: That's a bug in your code. You can post a different question with the updated code and heroku error log trace..